# Layout with two tabhost

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a problem with my android app. My application has two tabhost and It works well but the layout doesn't work well like the following picture:

[image]

The problem is that the FrameLayout overlaps with the lower tabhost and I dont solve it.

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TABHOST SUPERIOR -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabhost_sup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0"/>

                <ScrollView 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- TABHOST INFERIOR -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"/>

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0" 
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you nested too much layout. To solve your problem, you can try assign id for your INFERIOR relativelayout and in your superior layout just use `android:layout_above="@id/inferiorId"`

Comment: Nice! Now it works well. Thank you so much